# xcode simulator weird id

Tags: xcode6, ios-simulator

Recently install xcode 6.4 and instead of simulator 8.4, 8.3 i'm getting ids see below in the screenshot

[image]

any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because you have multiple devices with the same name and OS version.  Delete the duplicates from Xcode's Devices window (Window -> Devices).